# MySQL: Print counted values

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

```
+-------------+
| izvajalecID |
+-------------+
|          20 |
|          21 |
|          21 |
|          20 |
|          21 |
+-------------+
```

I would like to count all the unique ID's and print their values.

For example:

Unique ID's: **2**
Values: **20, 21**

I tried with the following query. Count works fine, but it returns only one(first) value. What am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct izvajalecID), s.izvajalecID FROM (SELECT izvajalecID FROM servis) s;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    izvajalecID
FROM 
    servis 
GROUP BY
    izvajalecID

UNION

SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT izvajalecID)
FROM 
    servis
```

[**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f1c3/1)

The last value in the set is for COUNT of unique values. You can also change them places and it will be the first value, just as you wish.

Comment: Values now work well, but count is now 1 (1 for every unique value). Should i just sum all of them using php or is there a mysql alternative that returns the final count?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT izvajalecID, COUNT(DISTINCT izvajalecID) as COUNT
FROM servis
GROUP BY izvajalecID
```

Result:

```
IZVAJALECID   COUNT
20            1
21            1
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5fa9/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT izvajalecID) AS COUNT, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT izvajalecID) AS ID
FROM servis
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of the uniq ids and get the list of the uniq Ids you need two queries.

One to count

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct izvajalecID) FROM servis GROUP BY izvajalecID;
```

And one to get the list.

```
SELECT distinct izvajalecID FROM servis GROUP BY izvajalecID;
```